# Disposing of a swfUpload instance

Tags: php, javascript, swfupload

I have a swfUpload instance that I want to make disapear after a succesful upload. I tried the destroy method but it caused a lot of javascript problems. So what I did is when the uploadSuccess event fires I get my div and set it's display to none. I then set the innerHTML of another div to show a thumbnail of the uploaded video. It works fine on every browser except internet explorer where it shows :

Message :

> Exception thrown and not caught Line : 451 Character : 2 Code : 0
>   URI : /js/swfupload/swfupload.js

and the submit button of my form doesn't work.

Here is the faulty function

```
SWFUpload.prototype.callFlash = function (functionName, argumentArray) {
argumentArray = argumentArray || [];

var movieElement = this.getMovieElement();
var returnValue, returnString;

// Flash's method if calling ExternalInterface methods (code adapted from MooTools).
try {
    returnString = movieElement.CallFunction('<invoke name="' + functionName + '" returntype="javascript">' + __flash__argumentsToXML(argumentArray, 0) + '</invoke>');
    returnValue = eval(returnString);
} catch (ex) {
    throw "Call to " + functionName + " failed";
}

// Unescape file post param values
if (returnValue != undefined && typeof returnValue.post === "object") {
    returnValue = this.unescapeFilePostParams(returnValue);
}

return returnValue;
```

};

And the uploadSuccess event :

```
function uploadSuccess(file, serverData) {
if (serverData != "")
{
    this.uploadError(file, SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.HTTP_ERROR, serverData);
}
else
{
    try {
        var progress = new FileProgress(file, this.customSettings.progressTarget);
        progress.setComplete();
        if (this.customSettings.langue == "fr")
        {
            progress.setStatus("Complété.");
        }
        else
        {
            progress.setStatus("Complete.");
        }
        progress.toggleCancel(false);

        document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = "<div id='cadre-image'><input type='hidden' name='txtFichier' value='" + file.name + "'><img id='imgPreview' src='images/thumbnailVideo.php?src=" + file.name + "&save=true' /><p>" + file.name + "</p></div>";
        document.getElementById("tdAjouter").innerHTML = "<input type='submit' value='Ajouter' />";
        var divupload = document.getElementById("upload");
        divupload.style.display = "none";

    } catch (ex) {
        this.debug(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swfupload destroy session? php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522623/swfupload-destroy-session-php)